# Cannot get KafkaConsumer messages without hanging

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I've written some data into my one-partition topic with a `KafkaProducer`, I'm trying to view this data using a `KafkaConsumer` by either looping through the consumer or `poll()`

```
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from kafka import KafkaProducer, KafkaConsumer, TopicPartition

consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',group_id='my-group',enable_auto_commit=False)
tp = TopicPartition(topic_name, 0)
consumer.assign([tp])
consumer.seek_to_end(tp)
last_offset = consumer.position(tp)
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')

stopWriting = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=10)
while datetime.now() < stopWriting:
    producer.send(topic='my-topic',value=str(datetime.now()).encode('utf-8'))
    time.sleep(1)

producer.close()
consumer.seek(tp, last_offset)

#looping through the consumer
for msg in consumer:
    print(msg)

# or looping through the polled messages 
for msg in consumer.poll():
    print(msg)
```

Neither one seems to work properly, the consumer loop does print out the messages, but always ended up hanging by an infinite loop within `kafka/consumer/group.py(886)_message_generator`. The poll loop doesn't print anything out at all. Is there something I'm missing to read out all of the newly made messages without hanging the program? I'm using Python 3.6.1 and `kafka-python` version 1.3.4

Comment: Try to do `consumer.poll()` in a loop. This is a good reference: https://www.confluent.io/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-the-new-apache-kafka-0-9-consumer-client/

Comment: The website wasn't that helpful as no exceptions were being found. But sticking with `poll()` was a good direction to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way with `poll()`, first you need a timeout with it because none of the messages are in the buffer. Next return a dict of `{TopicParition:[ConsumerRecord]}`, so you need to specify the topic partition that you want to read the messages from.

```
import sys
records = consumer.poll(timeout_ms=sys.maxsize)
for record in records[tp]:
    print(record)
```